# edit the gps.conf file

Tags: android, configuration, gps

How can I get or create gps.conf file based on user selection of area and load it onto the device? 
 I saw some times the gps.conf stored in /system/etc/gps.conf 
How can I edit this file based on user selection?

Thanks
Jetti

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You HAVE to root your phone
- Some chipsets don't even have
  gps.conf, they may use different
  filenames and may be present in a
  different file location or may not
  use it at all.

Your solution can only work for your phone.

Comment: Thanx for reply. But How can I make it Global to all the devices? Any Idea please share

Comment: If I use mandatory structure like "/system/etc/gps.conf". And I can read only from this file.Now How can I edit the file in /system/etc?     Which permission I need to give and how?